# Moving + filtering columns from one tab to another

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, formula, vlookup

In Google Sheets, I have a large amount of data with multiple columns in tab1. I want to copy three specific columns to tab2 (in the same sheet) and filter the information in these columns at the same time.

I've explored FILTER, INDEX and VLOOKUP but it's been a while since I worked with formulas. I can copy the columns with all the functions above, but I don't know how to apply a filter at the same time.

See example sheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ya_540h--1ohwVbVeH-R9cGEA8mV_bRUlVwi_9v2ojQ/edit

In the example I want to move three columns from tab1 to tab2, but filtered for 'blue' and 'square' in columnns B and E.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: Example sheet added to the original question.

Comment: Whats the backend logic on which columns needs to be filtered firsthand?! What if there's another *Blue* in Colum_C & *square* in Column_G, then how would the expected output look like?!

Comment: I need the information in Column A, but based on certain criteria which are (always) in Column B & E

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=filter({A:A,B:B,E:E},B:B="Blue",E:E="Square")
```

[image]